# Java - JPA @Basic and @Embedded annotations

Tags: java, jpa

I am learning JPA from [this tutorial](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/manual.html#jpa_overview_meta_basic).

I have some confusions in understanding the following annotations:

- `@Basic`
- `@Embedded`

> Fields of an embeddable type default to persistent, as if annotated with @Embedded.

If the fields of embeddable types default to persistent, then why would we need the `@Embedded` annotation

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `@Embeddable` annotation allows to specify a class whose instances are stored as intrinsic part of the owning entity. This annotation has **no attributes**.

```
@Embeddable
public class EmploymentPeriod {
     java.util.Date startDate;
     java.util.Date endDate;
     ...
}
```

The `@Embedded` annotation is used to specify a persistent field or property of an entity whose value is an instance of an embeddable class. By default, column definitions specified in the `@Embeddable` class apply to the table of the owning entity but **you can override them** using`@AttributeOverride`:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="startDate", column=@Column(name="EMP_START")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="endDate", column=@Column(name="EMP_END"))
})
public EmploymentPeriod getEmploymentPeriod() { ... }
```

---

Regarding the optional `@Basic` annotation, you may use it to configure the fetch type to `LAZY` and to configure the mapping to forbid null values (for non primitive types) with the `optional` attribute.

```
@Basic(fetch=LAZY)
protected String getName() { return name; }
```

You can also place it on a field or property to explicitly mark it as persistent (for documentation purpose).

Comment: Q1. If the fields or properties of embeddable types are by defualt persistent then why we need to add `@Embedded` annotation ? Q2. Can I use `@AttributeOverrides` annotation without `@Embedded` annotation? Could you please also throw some light on `@Basic`?

Comment: Q1. Because @Embedded allows to override column definitions Q2. No I don't think so. There is a good example illustrating this here: http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5.0.0/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/ch02s02s02s03.html

Comment: @Pascal What if there are no overrides? What's the purpose of `@Embedded`? Can it be left out?

Comment: @HendyIrawan: I have posted this as a question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31157700/2886891

Comment: Most usefull, concise and complete answer on this subject ! ;) got my +1

Answer (score 13):

In ORM mapping, the granularity of your object model can be finer than that of your database.

For example, you can have a `Person` record in your database which can be further decomposed to contain a reference to an `Address` object  in your model. That's where the `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` annotations come in. They simply state a relationship where one `Entity` can be stored as part of another.

As for the `@Basic` annotation, it's the simplest form of mapping which is applied by default to primitive types such as int and float and their wrappers as well as enums. More information can be had here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property

Answer (score 3):

> **@Basic**
>
> The  Basic annotation can be applied to a persistent property or
>   instance variable of any of the following types:
>
> Java primitive types,
>   wrappers of the primitive types, String,  java.math.BigInteger, 
>   java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date,  java.util.Calendar, 
>   java.sql.Date,  java.sql.Time,  java.sql.Timestamp, byte[], Byte[], 
>   char[], Character[], enums, and any other type that implements
>   java.io.Serializable.
>
> The use of the Basic annotation is optional for
>   persistent fields and properties of these types. If the  Basic
>   annotation is not specified for such a field or property, the default
>   values of the Basic annotation will apply.

Example:

```
@Basic
protected String name;
```

and

```
@Basic(fetch=LAZY)
protected String getName() { 
    return name; 
}
```

---

> **@Embedded**
>
> Specifies a persistent field or property of an entity whose value is
>   an instance of an embeddable class. The embeddable class must be
>   annotated as Embeddable.

Example 1:

```
@Embedded    
@AttributeOverrides({
       @AttributeOverride(name="startDate", column=@Column("EMP_START")),
       @AttributeOverride(name="endDate", column=@Column("EMP_END"))    
})        
public EmploymentPeriod getEmploymentPeriod() { ... }
```

Example 2:

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @EmbeddedId ProjectId id;
    //other fields
}


@Embeddable
Class ProjectId {
    int departmentId;
    long projectId;
}
```

[JSR Persistence Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) and [Source reference](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/field)