# @Embedded is mandatory or not

Tags: hibernate

I was going through the @Embeddable and @Embedded annotation in JPA. I used only @Embeddable annotation and still got the same result as for using the both annotation.

So what's the purpose of using the @Embedded annotation specifically.

Comment: And how is that related to embedded systems??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157700/is-the-jpa-embedded-annotation-mandatory

Comment: @Olaf It's related to hibernate framework.

Comment: @ike3 Still there is not accepted answer on that question.