# Hibernate value split into 2 columns. How to map?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-5.x

I got a legacy database which I want to keep as it is, but this causes some problems with hibernate.

My current problem is, that I have the field `private Calendar myTradeDateTime;` in my POJO and this is mapped to 2 columns.

The first column holds only the date information (e.g. '2013-05-14') and the second column holds only the time information (e.g. '10:09:12 PM'). Now I want to use hibernate to access both columns with just that 1 field. I would assume that I need some `@Converter` to deal with it, but I have no idea how that should be done and I couldn't find any info on this topic (2 columns into 1 field).

**So my question is, how can I map 2 columns into 1 field in hibernate 5.3?**

Answer (score 3):

As I explained in [this article](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-1-attribute-2-columns/), JPA and Hibernate map each entity attribute to a database column. But you can use a small workaround to achieve the requested mapping.

You first need 2 entity attributes that map the 2 database columns. If you use field-based access (you annotate the attributes and not the setters), you can skip the getter and setter methods for these attributes. You can then add a 3rd attribute, which is the one you will use in your business code. You need to annotate it with `@Transient` and calculate its value based on the other 2 attributes.

Here's a mapping that uses this approach to map a time (postedAtTime) and a date (postedAtDate) column to the `LocalDateTime postedAt` attribute.

```
@Entity
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String comment;

    private LocalDate postedAtDate;

    private LocalTime postedAtTime;

    @Transient
    private LocalDateTime postedAt;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getPostedAt() {
        if (postedAt == null) {
            this.postedAt = LocalDateTime.of(this.postedAtDate, this.postedAtTime);
        }
        return postedAt;
    }

    public void setPostedAt(LocalDateTime postedAt) {
        this.postedAt = postedAt;
        this.postedAtDate = postedAt.toLocalDate();
        this.postedAtTime = postedAt.toLocalTime();
    }
}
```

Please be aware, that you need to use the `postedAtDate` and `postedAtTime` attributes in your JPQL And Criteria queries. But as long as you work with the `Review` entity object, you don't need to know about these 2 internal attributes.

Answer (score 2):

When you use hibernate native API and hbm.xml it still works like that:

```
    <property name="dateMitUltimo" type="org.UTDateUltimo">
        <column name="DAT_ULTIMO" />
        <column name="SL_ULTIMO" />
    </property>
```

With UserType like that:

```
public class UTDateUltimo
    implements CompositeUserType {
```

Using the JPA-API of hibernate this no longer works :-(
Instead you can try the embedded feature. In xml this looks like:

```
<entity class="de.parcit.base.db.jpa.TestEmbedded" name="TestEmbedded">
    <table name="TEMBED" />

    <attributes>
        <!-- domain="ID" type="long" -->
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <!-- <generated-value strategy="TABLE" /> -->
        </id>

        <embedded name="dateMitUltimo" />

    </attributes>
</entity>

<embeddable class="de.parcit.base.db.jpa.DateJPA" access="FIELD">

    <convert converter="de.parcit.base.db.jpa.DateConverter" attribute-name="date" />

    <attributes>

        <!-- domain="Datum_Ultimo" -->
        <basic name="date">
            <column name="DAT_ULTIMO" />
        </basic>

        <!-- domain="SL_SI" -->
        <basic name="month">
            <column name="SL_ULTIMO" />
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</embeddable>
```

and

```
public class DateConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<Date, java.sql.Date> {
```

I didnt try this with annotations.

**Update:**

"embedded" can be used with annotations too.
Here is an example:
[Java - JPA @Basic and @Embedded annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578530/java-jpa-basic-and-embedded-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do such thing in Hibernate. I suggest to map both columns and create a getter and setter as you could see below (In addition of those you already have to create):

```
private LocalDate tradeDate;
private LocalTime tradeTime;
```

and a get/set method like:

```
public Calendar getMyTradeDateTime(){
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(this.tradeDate, this.tradeTime);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    return c.setTimeInMillis(dateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("-03:00"))*1000);
}
```

PS: To set the zoneoffset of your VM timezone. Can get it programmatically(?).

```
public void setMyTradeDateTime(Calendar c) {
   LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(c.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    this.tradeDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();
    this.tradeTime = dateTime.toLocalTime();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Entity
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String comment;

    private LocalDate postedAtDate;

    private LocalTime postedAtTime;

    @Transient
    private LocalDateTime postedAt;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getPostedAt() {
        if (postedAt == null) {
            this.postedAt = LocalDateTime.of(this.postedAtDate, this.postedAtTime);
        }
        return postedAt;
    }

    public void setPostedAt(LocalDateTime postedAt) {
        this.postedAt = postedAt;
        this.postedAtDate = postedAt.toLocalDate();
        this.postedAtTime = postedAt.toLocalTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).